# how to execute anonymous block of apex code in sublimeText 3 with mavensmate

Tags: mavensmate, sublime, execute-anonymous

I'm actually using sublimeText3 with mavensmate to code in apex. But i don't know how to execute anonymous block of code. Does anyone try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mavens mate server open a project

[image]

In upper left hand corner click on the open menu (3 lines)

[image]

Select Execute Anonymous

[image]

IMHO there are much better alternative out there now than MM/Sublime. I once loved MM/Sublime but I found IntelliJ Idea w/ Illuminated cloud. Others include aside.io, The Welkin Suite (wish had a mac version), etc

Comment: Just a note that there have been issues with latest API's

Comment: @Nonick - I would not doubt it which is why I moved away from MM/Sublime during the TLS 1.0 disablement and the developer stopping work on the project during that time. In all fairness for family. However, it forced me to look and I am glad I did. IntelliJ with IC is a sweet combination. Some of the webbed tools are great as well. Personally, I would look at other options.

Comment: Am setting up IntelliJ right now! Slowly starting to resolve the issues, resetting IDE allowed the creation of other files, external tables aren’t generated but that’s because for some reason diff menu was appearing on an OSX screen other than the visible one’s. If Project folder is selected, the context doesn’t allow the creation of SForce metadata but allows other lower level records, few other ‘quirks. Agree that I wouldn't be going to Mavensmate at the moment.

Comment: You need the illuminated cloud plugin as well. Lots of helpful videos with using it and IntelliJ as well. Also make sure version of IntelliJ is 2016.2.5 and not latest release. In latest jwtbrains has some major bugs that will be fixed in next few days

Comment: Thanks for concern @Eric. Got the system up and working. Still early days but am really enjoying the IDE. Sublime is great and revolutionised my world (coming away from Eclipse) but this feels like an actual developped IDE, not a text editor.

Comment: @Nonick I am glad you are liking it. Give the offline debugger a try and you will be amazed

Answer (score 1):

Using the MavensMate app, quite sure, it's using the "Execute Apex" option. But it is not compatible with last few API's https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/602

[image]